# Facebook : How to send a private message as a fanpage

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, python-2.7, xmpp

After some brave days of research, I decided to ask for help.

I'm trying to integrate xmpp I created, with the facebook chat.

Unable to send message to my profile but I want the message to be sent as a fan page. 
Even using the access_token and api_key, was not possible.

I've used the xmpppy sleekxmpp and all to no avail.

Could anyone inform how sending message as fan page?

Any solution in another language (java, php, c + + ....)